# objective c - dynamically resizing view height

Tags: objective-c

I've seen many questions regarding this topic, yet I cannot find one satisfactory answer.
I've created a sample view using interface builder, attached below:
[Layout sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwIZJ.png)

Now the text content is dynamic, and when I have a list of such views one underneath the other, I get to a strange state in which views overlap each other. I am looking for a simple way to get my view to resize itself, or at least expend to the size of all its subviews.

All the explanations I find have to do with a single label, in which their is a manual calculations of its size. Is there no simple mechanism provided by coca toch for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to subclass that superview containing all those other items. Then override -layoutSubviews method and in that method calculate your sizes and reposition the subviews.

Comment: Including the margins \ paddings I've entered manually? This seems unbelievable. Do all ios programmers do it?

Comment: Yes and until Lion, Mac programmers too.  The automagical layouts which were just introduced in OS X Lion , 26 years after the first version of Interface builder was released, are not yet available on iOS. It's not as bad as it sounds actually. If you look at Hillegass's iOS programming book, he shows how to create a NSTableViewCell subclass. You can apply the same technique to any UIVIew subclass.